# Auto-generated title based on last entry

Tags: titles, auto-generate

I am attempting to make one of my sections use auto-generated titles. I am making my first entry with a title like `8000`. What I need is the second entry to be titled `8001`, the third `8002`, etc. **Each entry must have a unique title in sequence.**

**This is the Title Format I tried using:**

`{{ craft.entries.section('scripts').last().title + 1 }}`

I created a test entry after that and it successfully generated a title similar to the last entry plus one. **However**, when I created a second test entry, the title remained the same as the first test entry, but the slug was `titlexx-1`. I made another test entry, same thing, with the slug `titlexx-2`.

What am I missing in my Title Format?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do what you're looking for:

```
{% if not object.id %}{{ craft.entries.section('scripts').order('postDate DESC').first().title + 1 }}{% else %}{{ object.title }}{% endif %}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this trigger ONLY when a brand new entry is saved? When the entry is updated and saved the title continues to be changed.

Comment: Updated answer...

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much! I had no idea that a field could be so powerful...